# Use Javascript in imacros

Tags: javascript, imacros

i am trying to create a imacros script. I want to add text to a CONTENTEDIT able DIV.

Here is what is am using:

```
URL GOTO=javascript:document.getElementsByClassName("input").innerHTML="Hello World";
```

But i am getting this error. wrong format of URL command, line 4 (Error code: 910)

I know URL GOTO is not a right function what can i use here instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try to write your code in such way:

```
URL GOTO=javascript:var<SP>v=document.getElementsByClassName("input")[0].innerHTML="Hello<SP>World";
```